# UINavigation Bar custom font

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have assigned a label to my navigation item.titleview

The problem is if I use system font then the label is centered on the navigation bar, but if I use custom font it is not.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All above three answers are helpful ..

To sum up :

1. From the above answers.. i can too say it is a bug
2. @*Dave Delong* .. i tried updating its frame via `titleView` ..only origin.x and width had an effect..y values didn't.
3. @*rob mayoff*  my first code include `size to fit` it didn't worked... then i tried many things.. making a button and setting its title.. etc.. still the bug persist.
4. *@rinzler* i tried that ..didn't worked for me.bug was still there with my font...might work for someone else..

So the solution was simple enough for me.. since my navigation bar title does not change.. i just replaced it with the text image.

using

```
UIImageView *TitleImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"MyImage.png"]];
self.navigationItem.titleView = TitleImage;  
[TitleImage release];
```

this won't work for those whose title changes.. Thanks all..

Comment: I have uploaded a test project here: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/26919672/navbartitleview.zip

Comment: can you help me with another thing... you helped me on a question earlier today .. so i have this code `  CGSize imagesize = CGSizeMake(67, 67);
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imagesize, NO, 0.0);
            NSLog(@" Converting ");
            [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,imagesize.width,imagesize.height)];
            newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext();  `  the image still comes in 67 x 67 even when i chosse iPhone Retina in simulator???

Comment: Please don't ask new and unrelated questions in comments.  Just create a new stackoverflow question.

Answer (score 2):

There is a way to work around this without adding a custom label. By setting `self.title` from the `viewDidLoad` method, the titleLabel will resize. However, you need to use a different title then defined in your storyboard. It won't call `sizeToFit` when the contents of the label doesn't change (which sounds logical to me).

Answer (score 1):

It is a known bug BUT you can circumvent it in the following way:

```
// adds a custom title label to the view
-(void)addNavBarTitle:(NSString*)titleText
{
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 360, 30)];     //  NOTE: YOU CAN ADD PADDING TO THE LABEL BY CHANGING ITS Y ORIGIN
    [label setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial-BoldMT" size:14]];                  // Use custom font if needed
    [label setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [label setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [label setText:titleText];                                                      // Dynamically change title. Else just explicitly set the string here
    label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem setTitleView:label];
    [label release];
}
```

That should do the trick,
Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a bug, so please file a report at https://bugreport.apple.com.  Including the code from which you generated these screenshots would be *extremely* helpful.

In the meantime, you can try positioning the label yourself via the `titleView` property of the corresponding `UINavigationItem`.

Answer (score 0):

The navigation bar centers the label based on its frame size.  If you have made the label's frame larger than necessary or put extra whitespace after the visible text, it will appear off-center.

To make the label exactly as big as necessary for its text, send the `sizeToFit` message to the label.  Or if you created the label in your nib, select the label and choose Editor > Size to Fit Content from the menu bar.

You could also set the label's `textAlignment` property to `UITextAlignmentCenter`.

Test project here: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/26919672/navbartitleview.zip

Comment: nice project.. apparently i think it is because of my custom font..thanks for all your help

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're supporting iOS 5+, then you want to use `[UINavigationBar appearance]` method to set custom title fonts, bar button fonts, bar button images, etc.

Read more here:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/21703/user-interface-customization-in-ios-6